Error Uploading image from Powerapps Gallery using Add Attachment action in flow
I have a gallery in which there is AddMedia control and on change of AddMedia control using the below logic
ClearCollect(
colImages,
{
ItemID: Gallery.Selected.ID,  // Link each image to an item ID in SharePoint
ImageFile: UploadedImage1.Image  // Capture the image file from the gallery control
}
);
Then passing the Image to flow as below on powerapps button click as below:
Animal_UploadImage.Run(
Last(AnimalFightChild).ID,
ThisRecord.UploadedImage1.Image , FileName
)
);
Then creating as flow but it is erroring when using Add Attachment control even trying as
base64ToBinary(triggerBody()['Base64ImageContent'])
datauritoBinary(triggerBody()['Base64ImageContent'])
creating as flow but it is erroring when using Add Attachment control even trying as
base64ToBinary(triggerBody()['Base64ImageContent'])
datauritoBinary(triggerBody()['Base64ImageContent'])
